# Align Stack Overflow logo on left column

Tags: discussion, design

I am not sure if this is the right place, but it's bothering me:

Can the logo be aligned on the left side? This goes for Meta and the whole of Stack Exchange really.

Current:

[image: Current]

Adding 2 "0" to the padding (for desktop size):

[image: Added 0's to padding]

---

#### Additionally

- This also causes the left side of the search bar to be aligned with the questions below (middle column

---

#### Hidden left bar

@AndreKool (see comments) caused me to have a look at the "hidden left sidebar" possibility and possibly try a fix.

Here **both** left *and* right do not align with the header content! (or vice versa!)

Find example below

[image: Hidden sidebar issue!]

A proposed fix is, when the left sidebar is hidden, is to make the header have the same max-width as the body: 1100 pixels.

There's some content that snaps out, but overall: better.

See below:

[image: Left sidebar header fix]

---

I am asking here because this is the tech site ;-)

Comment: And what would be your proposition fo the people that have the left side nav hidden?

Comment: @André Remove the logo for those users, _of course_. But in seriousness, users with the left side nav hidden wouldn't be affected by the "fix" proposed by the OP. The logo wouldn't be aligned with anything, but it isn't aligned with anything right now either. (Not that I think the misalignment is something that requires to be fixed).

Comment: @AndréKool Didn't know that was even possible, you caused me to look. Found that option and that's even worse than the current situation! Alignment ocd triggered! Does not align on the left AND the right! Nightmare! Shall have a quick look, but CSS really isn't a strong suite of mine :p (Just that I think this should've been part of the design, or at least a refactor to fix before release)

Comment: @AndréKool - please see edit :)

Comment: What problem does this proposition solve? How does this proposition make the site easier to use? As currently written, it sounds as if you simply want things aligned for the sake of being aligned.

Comment: @IInspectable - that is the whole point of design - you question the way something feels and you fix it to look correctly.  Sometimes design doesn't really mix well in functionality...its aesthetics, looks, etc.

Comment: @JonH: The whole point of design is to make rational decisions. This design change request neither evaluates, why the current design is the way it is, nor does it explain, why the change is useful. There are valid reasons to align items (e.g. to remove clutter) and there are valid reasons to not align items (to set them visually apart). I'm inclined to believe, that the top bar was placed where it is, as the result of a conscious thought process. Maybe this change request is, too, but it does nothing to help us see it.

Comment: @IInspectable - Right align, the logo doesn't align to the menu - hence OP posting question.  I don't understand your grudge.

Comment: @JonH: The OP is asking a question, for which they already know the answer: *"Yes, the logo [can] be aligned on the left side"*, as evidenced by their modified CSS. Since there isn't really a question here, I'm assuming that the OP is asking to have the alignment changed. If that is the rationale behind posting this, they need to explain, why that change is useful. You don't go around changing systems, just because you can. You need a stronger reason to justify taking the risk.

Comment: @IInspectable - That's rather odd - companies rarely ask you if they need to make a design change - they will do it based on color schemes, layout, other function factors, technology changes, and to help accessibility features.  You DON'T have to explain yourself - you do it.  You are complaining about nothing.  The 26 upvotes from others like yourself clearly ask the same thing.  An upvote means acceptance...26 others have the same thought process as OP.

Comment: @JonH: I don't think I can follow that line of thought. You first lay out valid reasons, why companies implement design changes, but then move on to suggest, that if you are a client/customer/user, you don't have to explain, why an existing design should be changed. Well, *that* is rather odd. Unless, of course, I'm just not understanding, what you are trying to get across.

Comment: @JonH: Now, come on, this is stretching it, really. You don't know any of the 26 users casting an up-vote, nor do you know their thought process that lead them to cast that vote. And you certainly don't know the thought process of the OP that made them post this design change request. I am complaining about precisely that.

Comment: I would like to see one of the folks behind the current design explain their reasoning for why it is unaligned. As it stands, imo at least, the proposed alignment looks much better as it creates a better sense of sync amongst the UI elements.

Comment: Stackoverflow and Stackoverflow Meta both design logos are different as compared to width. if they aligned with left sidebar, still there will be issue for stackoverflow Meta. I feel they did not missed the trick here, it's for a reason. I have not upvote/downvote this. I feel current design looks better.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm requesting change because I, myself, prefer an aligned look. Also, currently there's 33 upvotes and 7 downvotes, so the "yea"'s are in the upper hand for this one, versus the "nay"'s. I also see no reason to not align something like this, because not aligning it looks, in my opinion, cheap and unprofessional. That's just me. What problem does it solve? Technically none. Aesthetically it fixes misalignment. Again, just me. (And I've not even mentioned the footer! It offends me in the same way! :p)

Comment: @JonH Thanks for the defense in my absence ;-) Glad to see some (most according to votes) think the same way I do.

Comment: @BrianHowell I'm sorry about that. But I did use MS Paint for that! And the Windows Snipping Tool! The most important tools on any computer! Really!

Comment: I think it’d be best to remove the left sidebar. 

Comment: FWIW, they appear to align on iPad in portrait. At least the 10.5” model.

Comment: Profile > settings

Comment: @GabrielLovetro: The top bar is disjoint from other UI elements on the page. Aligning it with those introduces the notion, that they were connected, but they aren't. The page floats underneath it. If it were aligned, I would expect it to scroll with the page. The requested change is thus counter-intuitive.

Comment: If you remove the 15 pixels of padding from the `div` for the top bar, it lines up with the `div` for the left column (to the pixel) which makes me think it was intentional by the designers. This is true of all the stack exchange sites that have a left column navigation bar.

Comment: @GrantSanders Not quite sure which top bar you mean. Can't replicate the effect you describe. Could you put it in an answer with a before/after screenshot and a preference? (Can't replicate because `<body>` has "new-topbar" class, `<header>` has "top-bar", 2nd has no padding. First has 50 padding all around, but no effect on header itself when reduced to 35px)

Answer (score 10):

I'll be honest, this doesn't personally matter much to me either way. If it stays the same that's fine with me and if they change it, it's not going to ruin my day either.

That said, I *would* like to offer a slightly different perspective that, if you can internalize it, might help you feel less bothered should things stay the same.

**When I look at the page, I see the logo as aligned with the left side.**

Now, I know: You've got perfectly good screenshots illustrating your point. Those red lines are obviously straight up and down and do not overlap. And no, your screenshot is in no way different from the way my browser renders the page. So why do I see them as aligned? Am I insane? Are you reading the ramblings of a person disconnected from reality? ...Well maybe.

But in this case I'm simply "seeing" more to the logo than you do. I'm seeing the icon and the text, but I'm also looking at it as if the logo has a wide border on all four sides. Similarly, the search bar has a much thinner border and there is a small, invisible, separator between the two:

[image: Screenshot with borders around elements]

Now, is that what the SO designers were actually going for? I have no idea. But if, in their infinite wisdom, they decide *not* to align the logo's icon with the text of the sidebar, perhaps if you can bring yourself to "see" things this way it will be slightly less offensive to you.

As I say, I personally would be happy with either and I wish you and everyone else happiness with it as well- whether that happiness comes from a design change or from being able to change your perspective on the design.

Comment: Interesting way of looking at it. With my ramblings above I obviously cannot agree with your perspective, though I see where you're coming from. However, with looking at it the way you are, how do you explain the then "sticking out" bit of the selected "Questions" in the image you provided? In my perspective that would cause the alignment line on the left to move to the left, then causing an unexplained (or misaligned) whitespace to the left of the logo, coming back to my question ;)

Comment: Do understand, I wrote that because it bothered me. If it's thought out to be that way, so be it. Just thought to mention it. If nothing is ever done with it, that's fine with me also, however much my eye would twitch. Because: once seen, it cannot be unseen. ;-)